# Determine whether the current Pacific time zone is PST or PDT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

We have some Ruby (in a Rails context) that parses expressed time integers into a datetime, and we need to ensure the datetime is parsed into Pacific time:

```
DateTime.new(2012, 11, 17, 3, 2, 0, 'PST')
```

However we need to change this to PDT ~half the year. How can we tell at runtime whether we should pass PST or PDT?

Comment: @jonrsharpe why edit the title to remove the Ruby preface? That makes it immediately apparent in search results that this is a question about Ruby and not e.g. Python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: Are there studies of the search engines that actually parse tags? I have often ended up here on a non-relevant technology answer, and in those cases a core technology preface would have saved me the time

Comment: Note that the `DateTime` class is intended for historical dates, see [When should you use `DateTime` and when should you use `Time`?](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/DateTime.html#class-DateTime-label-When+should+you+use+DateTime+and+when+should+you+use+Time-3F)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not attempt to figure out whether to pass PST or PDT (or their equivalent offsets) yourself.  Instead, use a time zone identifier, such as those from [the IANA tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (ex: `America/Los_Angeles` for US Pacific Time), and allow the underlying data for that zone to determine the appropriate offset for the given date and time.

In Ruby, there are a few different ways to accomplish this.

- You can use the [TZInfo](https://tzinfo.github.io/) library:

  ```rb
  require 'tzinfo'

  tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/Los_Angeles')
  dt = tz.local_datetime(2012, 11, 17, 3, 2, 0)
  ```

  I believe this library is already included with Rails.
- You can use the [timezone](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone) library (though I'm not sure how it differs from tzinfo precisely)

  ```rb
  require 'timezone'

  tz = Timezone['America/Los_Angeles']
  dt = tz.time_with_offset(Time.new(2012, 11, 17, 3, 2, 0))
  ```
- In Rails specifically, you *can* use the [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) class, though I don't recommend it.

  ```rb
  tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Pacific Time (US & Canada)']
  dt = tz.local(2012, 11, 17, 3, 2, 0)
  ```

  The reasons for not recommending this approach are described in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), in the section at the very bottom titled "Rails TIme Zone Identifiers".  Alas, if you have an application that needs them - they do still exist in Rails.

Comment: Note - example code copied from docs.  Please forgive any minor typos or omissions.  Thanks.